# Should a question asking for a piece of code to be explained in detail be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags

I found [a question today where a user wants the community to explain a piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44545675/php-code-which-convert-pdf-doc-file-to-string-or-txt) he found and add comments to every single line explaining what that line does. I initially thought these types of question were off topic, but I can't find a flag to reflect that.

I am not trying to have this serial down voted or immediately closed, but I would like to know if I am right about it being off topic and what steps I should take in the future.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Questions of that form are pretty much always going to be Too Broad.

If there is a *specific* question about a *specific* part of the code (that mentions what it is that they don't understand about it, or at least what they want explained about it), then the question could be narrowed sufficiently, but an "Explain the whole thing to me" question is going to be Too Broad.

Comment: ok that makes sense. Thanks!